# Python to excel writing problem with compling errors

Tags: python, excel

"Hello world!"
I am tried to create a EXCEL file from Python TKinter page.I have a Tkinter page with more textbooks when the user can put some text(Ex: Name, Age, Job etc) and I want to put all the infos that user write in an EXCEL file name after the user. I want to do this when he is pressing a button (name submit). All my textbooks and dates from those textbooks are strings and this is the code that provides all the errors(just when i click the button)

1. List item

   f = float(token)
   TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'type'
   return self.func(*args)
   worksheet.write(row, col+1, score)
   return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
   raise TypeError("Unsupported type %s in write()" % type(token))
   TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'type'> in write()

```
for name, score in (expenses):
worksheet.write(row, col, name)
worksheet.write(row, col+1, score)
col+=1
```

Comment: try use explicit positional parameter name, such as `row=x, column=y`

Comment: I think perhaps show a bit more code?